# Default value in select query for null values in postgres

Tags: postgresql, null, group-by

I have a table with sales Id, product code and amount. Some places product code is null. I want to show **Missing** instead of null. Below is my table.

```
salesId     prodTypeCode    amount
1           123              150
2           123              200
3           234             3000
4           234              400
5           234              500
6           123              200
7           111              40
8           111              500
9                           1000
10          123              100
```

I want to display the total amount for every `prodTypeCode` with the option of If the prodTypeCode is null then **Missing** should be displayed.

```
select (CASE WHEN prodTypeCode IS NULL THEN
   'Missing'
    ELSE
    prodTypeCode
    END) as ProductCode, SUM(amount) From sales group by prodTypeCode
```

Above query giving error. Please suggest me to overcome this issue. I ahve created a [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9d25d/1)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The problem is a mismatch of datatypes; `'Missing'` is text, but the product type code is numeric.

Cast the product type code to text so the two values are compatible:

```
select (CASE WHEN prodTypeCode IS NULL THEN
   'Missing'
    ELSE
    prodTypeCode::varchar(40)
    END) as ProductCode, SUM(amount) From sales group by prodTypeCode
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9d25d/2).

Or, simpler:

```
select coalesce(prodTypeCode::varchar(40), 'Missing') ProductCode, SUM(amount)
from sales
group by prodTypeCode
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9d25d/4).

Answer (score 10):

Perhaps you have a type mismatch:

```
select coalesce(cast(prodTypeCode as varchar(255)), 'Missing') as ProductCode,     
       SUM(amount)
From sales s
group by prodTypeCode;
```

I prefer `coalesce()` to the `case`, simply because it is shorter.

Comment: Your example is missing a parenthesis after 'Missing'.

Answer (score 5):

I tried both answers and in my case both did not work. What ended up helping was this:

```
SELECT 
COALESCE(NULLIF(prodTypeCode,''), 'Missing') AS ProductCode,        
SUM(amount)
From sales s
group by prodTypeCode;
```